# How can I invoke button in datatemplate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have problem with worked button. I created pattern for display items with ObservableCollection but my button doesn't work.

Here I display items with dosent worked button

```
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Vehicles}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Task:VehcileTask/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Here is code displayed button with VehicleTask

```
            <Button Background="Red" Content="Delete"  Command="{Binding DeleteItem}">
            
        </Button>
```

This is command to invoke

```
        public ICommand DeleteItem { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the DeleteItem command is a property of your main ViewModel, and not the individual data items, then you need to reference it via relative data binding.

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

You also need to include the item to be deleted as the CommandParameter of the Button

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

and to reference that parameter value within your command's corresponding method.